# Why is only part of the file list of a variable processed in this Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have this test Makefile which runs ok. It makes three symbolic links and echoes the link names when I do 'make'.

```
XXX = x.c y.c z.c
all : | $(XXX)
    cat $(XXX)
$(XXX) :
    @echo making XXX
    ln -s ../src/$@ $@
clean :
    rm -f $(XXX)
```

So I applied this to my real case. As a background I'm trying to use a trick which is making symbolic links for source files in the place where I run make and removing the symbolic links by 'make clear' because the existing Makefile structure (with many included patches) assumes the sources are in the same directory. So I'm taking a easy way without fixing the Makefile tree..

I run under a directory called rtn5_fpga and the sources are in ../src directory. The Makefile sets a couple of variables and includes ../Makefile.base. Here is the ../Makefile.base.

```
#
#  Makefile
#

#
#  RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH is typically set in an environment variable
#

# optional managers required
MANAGERS=all

# C source names

CSRCS = init.c
COBJS_ = $(CSRCS:.c=.o)
COBJS = $(COBJS_:%=${ARCH}/%)

include $(RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH)/Makefile.inc
include $(RTEMS_CUSTOM)
include $(PROJECT_ROOT)/make/leaf.cfg
XCFLAGS = -I../../include -qnolinkcmds -T ../../lib/linkcmds.abtn5

OBJS= $(COBJS) $(CXXOBJS) $(ASOBJS)

all: | $(XXX) ${ARCH} $(PGM) RUNTCL

$(PGM): $(OBJS)
    $(make-exe)
.DEFAULT_TARGET := all

RUNTCL:
    echo 'system_init' > run.tcl
    echo 'load_image o-optimize/sieve.exe' >> run.tcl
    echo 'run $(_RAM_START)' >> run.tcl

clean:
    -$(RM) -r $(ARCH)
    -$(RM) $(XXX)

XXX = init.c system.h config.h

$(XXX) :
    ln -s ../src/$@  $@
```

This is the result of 'make clean' and 'make'.

```
ckim@stph45:~/test/rtn5_fpga] make clean
at Makefile.inc RTEMS_API = @RTEMS_API@
rm -f a.out core mon.out gmon.out
rm -f -r 
rm -f -r  a.out *.o *.BAK Depends-o-optimize.tmp
rm -f -r o-optimize o-debug
rm -f -r o-optimize
rm -f init.c system.h config.h
ckim@stph45:~/prj/abts/rtems-qt/applications/sieve/rtn5_fpga] make
at Makefile.inc RTEMS_API = @RTEMS_API@
test -d o-optimize || mkdir o-optimize
ln -s ../src/init.c  init.c
sparc-ab-rtems-gcc --pipe -B/some/dir/path/lib/ -specs bsp_specs -qrtems   -Wall -I../../include -qnolinkcmds -T ../../lib/linkcmds.abtn5 -O4    -mtune=v8 -msoft-float -fcommon -DTARGET_ALDEBARAN       -c   -o o-optimize/init.o init.c
init.c:15:20: fatal error: system.h: No such file or directory
 #include "system.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [o-optimize/init.o] Error 1
```

The problem is, when making $(XXX) at the bottom of ../Makefile.base, it only makes one symbolic link, not three links. What is the problem?

Comment: Try moving `XXX = init.c system.h config.h` above `all`.

Comment: I'd try making `init.c` depend on `system.h`, if the make rule for `init.c` does not trigger for all of `XXX` at once.

Comment: @TNW, wow, that solved it. Thanks! Why is it like that? That was solved but I'm facing another problem. I'll add to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

@TNW had it right - simply move the definition of `XXX` before the `all` target.  What's happening is that the line:

```
all: | $(XXX) ${ARCH} $(PGM) RUNTCL
```

is evaluating `$(XXX)`, which is effectively empty, at that point.  So, that's not what's causing the link for init.c to be created.

The reason it makes a link for init.c is that it's a dependency of other targets ($(PGM) via init.o).

GNU Make uses lazy evaluation of variables and functions.  However, lines specifying target and dependency lists are evaluated as they're encountered, in the file.